# Automake generates an empty .dirstamp file

Tags: linux, automake

I added 'AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = subdir-objects' to Makefile.am and a .dirstamp was created, what is .dirstamp and what's the relationship between 'subdir-objects' and this file?

Comment: `.dirstamp` is a Make convention. It's a hidden file which will have its own make target, and is used to ensure a directory exists. Such a target (e.g. `$(DIR)/.dirstamp`) will be used a dependency for other targets that require the directory to exist.

Comment: @Dennis is it safe to delete? And what are the generated files named "-g" (The file name is -g)?

Comment: Why would you want to delete a file that will re-generated on the next run anyway? And what exactly are you referring to with "The file name is `-g`)? That looks like a change in topic?